# How to show that $a,\ b\in {\mathbb Q},\ a^2+b^2=1\Rightarrow a=\frac{s^2-t^2}{s^2+t^2},\ b= \frac{2st}{s^2+t^2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I want show the following $$a,\ b\in {\mathbb Q},\ a^2+b^2=1\Rightarrow a=\frac{s^2-t^2}{s^2+t^2},\ b= \frac{2st}{s^2+t^2},\ s,\ t\in{\mathbb Q} $$

How can we prove this ?

[Add] Someone implies that we must use pythagorean triple :

Let $$ a=\frac{n}{m},\ b= \frac{s}{k},\ (m,n)=(s,k)=1$$

Then $$ k^2n^2+s^2m^2=m^2k^2 \Rightarrow n^2|(k^2-s^2),\ k^2|m^2
  $$ so that we have $$n^2+ s^2=k^2,\ (n,s)=1,\ k=m$$ We complete the proof by the following

Proof of pythagorean triple : $$a^2+
b^2=c^2,\ (a,b)=1$$ Then which form do $a,\ b,\ c$ have ? We have $$
\frac{c+a}{b}=\frac{A}{B}=\frac{b}{c-a},\ (A,B)=1$$

So $$ (c+a)B^2=bAB=(c-a)A^2 $$

So $$ c-a=B^2t,\ c+a=A^2t$$ That is $$ b=tAB,\
c=\frac{t}{2}(A^2+B^2),\ a= \frac{t}{2}(A^2-B^2)
$$

$(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow t=2$ or $1$ If $t=1$, then $AB$ is odd. So we can derive a contradiction.

Comment: You should definitely indicate what background you have, as there are some elementary proofs using only modular arithmetic, and there are some harder proofs using algebraic geometry techniques et cetera.

Comment: It is exercise in 584 p of Floote and Dummit's book. It is a problem in Galois section.

Comment: You can use any $s$ and $t$ such that $s / t = b / (1 - a)$ (e.g., just reduce the fraction $b / (1-a)$ to lowest terms).  In the special case where $a = 1$, use $s = 1$ and $t = 0$.  Actually, since $s$ and $t$ are allowed to be rational, it's enough to use $s = b / (1-a)$ and $t = 1$ (again, except in the case $a = 0$).

Comment: Thank you. We can diminish calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the line through $(-1,0)$ with slope $\frac{t}{s}$. Compute the other point on the circle that the line passes through.

So, points on the line are of the form $(p,q)=(-1+\alpha s,\alpha t)$ and the points on the circle have $p^2+q^2=1$, or $1-2\alpha s + \alpha^2(s^2+t^2)=1$ or $$\alpha\left(\alpha(s^2+t^2)-2s\right)=0$$

$\alpha=0$ gives $(-1,0)$, the original point, and $\alpha=\frac{2s}{s^2+t^2}$ gives the other point. $p=-1+\frac{2s^2}{s^2+t^2}=\frac{s^2-t^2}{s^2+t^2}$ and $q=\frac{2st}{s^2+t^2}$.

Now, if $p,q$ are rational, $p\neq -1$, the line through $(p,q)$ and $(-1,0)$ has rational slope, specifically, $\frac{q}{p+1}$. (You have to treat the case $p=-1$ sepearately.)

This technique works for any quadratic and the rational points. If you have one known one rational point, $(p_0,q_0)$ you can take any pair of integers $(s,t)$ and take the line from our base rational point in the direction $(s,t)$ and get another rational point. For example, the equaion:

$$p^2+q^2=2$$

has obvious root $(-1,-1)$ and $(p,q)=(-1+\alpha s,-1+\alpha s)$ gives $1-2\alpha(s+t) + \alpha^2(s^2+t^2)=1$ or:

$$\alpha\left(\alpha(s^2+t^2)-2(s+t)\right)=0$$

or $\alpha=\frac{2(s+t)}{s^2+t^2}$ for the non-zero answer, and then:

$$(p,q)=\left(\frac{s^2+2st-t^2}{s^2+t^2},\frac{t^2+2st-s^2}{s^2+t^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$ rational. Then, 
Set $s=1$ and $t=\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ then $a=\frac{s^2-t^2}{s^2+t^2}$ and $b=\frac{2st}{s^2+t^2}$.

To show that $t$ is rational, remark that $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$.

Q.E.D.

And actually it works for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Well, the assertion is that $s,t\in\mathbb Q$, so that doesn't work for $a,b\in\mathbb R$. You have to show your $t$ is rational when $a,b$ are rational...

Comment: If the person who put a downvote could explain !!! It's of course obvious that if $a=\sin x$ and $b=\cos x$ are rational then $\tan\frac{x}{2}$ is rational also !! Indeed, $\tan\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+1}$.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it did seem important to show $t$ was rational. (I knew it was, which is why I didn't downvote.) The comment about $a,b\in\mathbb R$ also made it seem like you missed the requirement that $s,t\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ok, I'll precise it in my comment. Thanks,